# kotlin script with aws sdk error: unresolved reference: aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, kotlin-script

In a kotlin script, trying to use the AWS SDK results in an error when trying to import the  packages

```
#!/usr/bin/env kotlin

@file:DependsOn("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.1")
@file:DependsOn("aws.sdk.kotlin:dynamodb:0.30.1-beta")

import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.model.ListTablesRequest


runBlocking {
    val ddb = DynamoDbClient.fromEnvironment()

    println("starting")
}
```

results in this error

```
test.main.kts:7:8: error: unresolved reference: aws
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient
       ^
test.main.kts:8:8: error: unresolved reference: aws
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.model.ListTablesRequest
       ^
```

the Kotlin coroutine import works but I can't figure out why the AWS import doesn't

I've tried to use a @file:DependsOn with a non-existing sdk version to make sure that resolving the dependency works and it fails as expected so I know the script is resolving and installing the AWS SDK successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-kotlin/issues/626#issuecomment-1147804042):

> As of 0.16.0, we've switched to Kotlin Multiplatform builds for AWS service clients. This results in splitting the "common" artifacts from the platform specific ones (e.g. JVM)

Using gradle or maven this change is transparent to consumers but for scripts you need to use the -jvm artifacts like

`@file:DependsOn("aws.sdk.kotlin:dynamodb-jvm:0.32.5-beta")`

instead of

`@file:DependsOn("aws.sdk.kotlin:dynamodb:0.32.5-beta")`